# MS Access SQL Query to report daily figures for the whole year even when no sales made on a particular day

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, inner-join

I've been asked to produce a datasheet/exportable output to excel that shows the total DAILY revenue from event bookings.

If you imagine Dates along the top as Column Headings, with 'Event subtypes' (IE Wedding, Meeting, Seminar etc) as Rows, where the financial value of the income from each event subtype is summed and shown in the corresponding column of the 'date event start'.

I've already coded a crosstab report that shows this summed by month. The code for that report is shown below and works OK, but my finance guy wants to see daily figures for each day of the year, including "0" for each day where no data actually exists within the database. I cant seem to:

- Create code to show results by day (im using the code pasted below
  as a starting point)
- Get the dates table to join so that I can
  show all dates even the ones where there are no events.

My database has the following tables:

```
Dates (ID, Dates = DateTime values from 1/1/2017 - 31/12/2117)

Enquiries (ID, [Customer ID], [Event Name],[Main Status],[Date Event Start],[Event Sub Category])

Financials (ID, [Enquiry ID], [Estimated Income], [Actual Income])

Customers (ID, [CustName] etc)
```

Sql query :

```
SELECT enquiries.[event name], 
       enquiries.[main status], 
       enquiries.[date event start], 
       enquiries.[event sub category], 
       financials.[actualincome], 
       financials.[estimatedincome], 
       enquiries.id, 
       Year([date event start])            AS [Year], 
       Month([date event start])           AS [Month], 
       Datepart("q", [date event start])   AS Quarter, 
       Format([date event start], "mmmm")  AS [Month Name], 
       ( Month([date event start]) MOD 3 ) AS MonthOfQuarter, 
       Switch(enquiries.[main status] = 'PIPELINE ENQUIRY' 
               OR enquiries.[main status] = 'Booking Form Sent', 
       financials.[estimatedincome])       AS EstimatedPipelineIncome, 
       Switch(enquiries.[main status] = 'CONFIRMED BOOKING' 
               OR enquiries.[main status] = 'Ts & Cs and Quote Sent' 
               OR enquiries.[main status] = 'Signed Ts & Cs Received', 
       financials.[actualincome])          AS ConfirmedIncome, 
       Switch(enquiries.[main status] = 'EVENT COMPLETED', 
       financials.[actualincome]) 
                                           AS CompletedIncome 
FROM   customers 
       INNER JOIN (enquiries 
                   INNER JOIN financials 
                           ON enquiries.id = financials.[enquiry id]) 
               ON customers.id = enquiries.[customer id] 
WHERE  (( ( enquiries.[main status] ) = "pipeline enquiry" 
           OR ( enquiries.[main status] ) = "booking form sent" 
           OR ( enquiries.[main status] ) = "confirmed booking" 
           OR ( enquiries.[main status] ) = "ts & cs and quote sent" 
           OR ( enquiries.[main status] ) = "signed ts & cs received" 
           OR ( enquiries.[main status] ) = "event completed" )) 
ORDER  BY enquiries.[date event start];
```

I have looked through similar questions and answers to this problem for 3 weeks on SO - but I cant seem to get those to work with my own instance as I am having problems with the SQL.

Is anyone able to help provide the SQL code that will help me add the Dates table into this SQL appropriately, and modify the query to resolve this problem?

This is my first post so please point out where I need to provide more info or ask things in a different way to help!

**UPDATE**:

The following code works to pull back the full list of dates with the events correctly aligned where they exist, but doesnt include the code to join the financial table to add the corresponding monetary values as I cant seem to nest the joins correctly:

```
SELECT Dates.Dates, Enquiries.[Event Sub Category], Financials.ActualIncome, Financials.[Total Booking Value Incl VAT]
FROM Dates LEFT JOIN Enquiries ON Dates.[Dates] = Enquiries.[Date Event Start];
```

Therefore I actually need the below to work, but cant get it to:

```
SELECT Dates.Dates, Enquiries.[Event Sub Category], Financials.ActualIncome, Financials.[Total Booking Value Incl VAT]
FROM (Enquiries INNER JOIN Financials ON Enquiries.[ID] = Financials.[Enquiry ID]) LEFT JOIN Dates ON Dates.[Dates] = Enquiries.[Date Event Start];
```

Comment: I assume that you want to join both tables on `Enquiries.[Date Event Start] = Dates.SomeDate`. If i'm right, you have to `right join` Dates table with your query. Please read this: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins). This might help you to understand how to achieve your goals.

Comment: I think the Enquiries.[Date Event Start] = Dates.SomeDate seems sensible - but this is the area where I am confused. For reference, the other tables are currently joined as: Enquiries.ID = Financials.[EnquiriesID] as a one to many; and Customers.ID = Enquiries.[CustomersID] as one to many.

Comment: See if this helps https://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3844021/Reporting-whats-not-there.htm

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in the comment to the question, you have join `[Dates]` table using `left join` (i was wrong earlier), which enables you to get all dates from [Dates] table and corresponding data from other tables. Please, refer the link i provided in the comment.

Tip: use [table aliases](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/alias.php). It causes that SQL code is more readible.

Take a look at this query:

```
SELECT D.[EventDate], E.[Event Name], E.[MAIN STATUS], 
    E.[Event Sub Category], F.[ActualIncome], F.[EstimatedIncome],
    E.ID, Year(D.[EventDate]) AS [Year], Month(D.[EventDate]) AS [Month],
    DatePart("q",D.[EventDate]) AS Quarter, Format(D.[EventDate],"mmmm") AS [Month Name],
    (Month(D.[EventDate]) Mod 3) AS MonthOfQuarter,
    Switch(E.[MAIN STATUS]='PIPELINE ENQUIRY' Or E.[MAIN STATUS]='Booking Form Sent', F.[EstimatedIncome]) AS EstimatedPipelineIncome,
    Switch(E.[MAIN STATUS]='CONFIRMED BOOKING' Or E.[MAIN STATUS]='Ts & Cs and Quote Sent' Or E.[MAIN STATUS]='Signed Ts & Cs Received',F.[ActualIncome]) AS ConfirmedIncome,
    Switch(E.[MAIN STATUS]='EVENT COMPLETED',F.[ActualIncome]) AS CompletedIncome
FROM [Dates] D LEFT JOIN (
        Customers C INNER JOIN (
            Enquiries E INNER JOIN Financials F ON E.ID = F.[Enquiry ID])
                ON C.ID = E.[Customer ID])
            ON D.EventDate = E.[Date Event Start]
WHERE (((E.[MAIN STATUS])="PIPELINE ENQUIRY" Or 
    (E.[MAIN STATUS])="Booking Form Sent" Or 
    (E.[MAIN STATUS])="CONFIRMED BOOKING" Or 
    (E.[MAIN STATUS])="Ts & Cs and Quote Sent" 
    Or (E.[MAIN STATUS])="Signed Ts & Cs Received" 
    Or (E.[MAIN STATUS])="EVENT COMPLETED"))
ORDER BY E.[Date Event Start];
```

Please, note that i have no access to your data, so above sql code can contain error(s).

Comment: I think I have confused you as the 'Dates' table just contains a list of every date from 2017 through to 2017; it doesnt contain the event dates, those are referenced in Enquiries.[Date Event Start]. I tried your code and it returned the list of Events but with no additional data showing dates where there are no events. Thank you and I'll take a look at the link you kindly provided also.

Comment: @Jess, i called that field `EventDate`, because you did not provide the names of fileds in [Dates] table. As per your requirements, you wanted to show all dates, so, don't be surprised that there are rows with dates, but without details. This means [Enquires] table does not contain corresponding data based on [Date Event Start] (which is equal to [EventDate]). Keep closer look at `right join` statement and read recommended article. Cheers! Maciej

Comment: ah no Im sorry I havent been clear with my reply. Apologies. I meant to say I tried your code and it ONLY returned the list of Events as before, but it did not return any dates where there is no data as I had wanted it to. IE the query performed in the same manner as it had done before I posted the question. I will look at that article for sure and will get there eventually! Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong, you have to use `left join`. Well, sometimes such of things happen.

Comment: No problem - I have tried the code you kindly posted with left join, but the error "Join expression not supported" appears so it doesnt execute. (It executed with right join). The joining aspect is the area where I'm weak in understanding, so i'll digest and review further. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems that left joins have to be nested inside inner joins. Despite reading all the documentation on syntax for this I can find, it is just far too complicated for me to understand. I really need an example please. It may be that there is a simple way to do this starting from scratch, not using the code I posted. I've never been this confused before!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. The answer was:

```
SELECT Dates.Dates, Enquiries.[Event Sub Category], Financials.ActualIncome, Financials.EstimatedIncome

FROM Dates LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                     Enquiries.[Date Event Start],
                     Enquiries.[Event Sub Category],
                     Financials.ActualIncome,
                     Financials.EstimatedIncome
                   FROM
                   Enquiries INNER JOIN Financials

                   ON Enquiries.ID = Financials.[Enquiry ID] )  AS sub ON Dates.Dates= sub.[Date Event Start];
```